# Standard Industrial Classification (SIC) Code in Compustat Fundamentals

Tags: fama-french, crsp

I would like to sort companies according to the Fama-French 48 industry levels. For that, I need the Compustat Standard Industrial Classification (SIC) code. In the web interface of WRDS, I could simply select the field SIC. However, I need to get the compustat data via an SQL query but comp.funda does not have an entry SIC (only SICH). Does someone know if I can simply use SICH or where I can find it? I know that the CRSP SIC code is stored in the SICCD field of CRSP's monthly stock names (msenames) file. Is there a similar file for Compustat data?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Compustat Standard Industrial Classification (SIC) code is contained in the header file comp.namesd and can be merged on GVKEY with comp.funda or comp.fundq